# Gson can not cast an Object

Tags: android, gson

I call a request network to my server, and server always response a format json look like this format below:

```
{

   "error": 200,
   "message": "Login Success",
   "message_app": "abcxyz",
   "data": {
     "client_id": "1423423",
     "client_secret": "64646456546"
   }
 }
```

Only jsonObject **data** is include different field for each kind of request. 
Example for a new response:

```
{

   "error": 200,
   "message": "Get product success",
   "message_app": "vcxvxcv",
   "data": {
     "product_title": "Product A",
     "product_desc": "This is a description for product A"
   }
 }
```

So I decide to make a general class call ServerResult include a field "Object" so that I can cast it to a specific object.

//**ServerResult.class**

```
public class ServerResult {
    private int error;
    private String message;
    private String message_app;
    private Object data;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessageApp() {
        return message_app;
    }

    public void setMessageApp(String messageApp) {
        this.message_app = messageApp;
    }

    public int getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(int error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public String getMessage_app() {
        return message_app;
    }

    public void setMessage_app(String message_app) {
        this.message_app = message_app;
    }
}
```

//Client.java

```
public class Client {

    private String client_id;
    private String client_secret;

    public String getClientId() {
        return client_id;
    }

    public void setClientId(String client_id) {
        this.client_id = client_id;
    }

    public String getClientSecret() {
        return client_secret;
    }

    public void setClientSecret(String client_secret) {
        this.client_secret = client_secret;
    }
}
```

After request finished, I convert json to a ServerResult object by GSON:

```
@Override    
  public void onResponse(String response) {              
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     ServerResult serverResult = gson.fromJson(response, ServerResult.class); //convert json String to ServerResult object

  }
```

And then cast Data object to a Client object

```
Client client = (Client)serverResult.getData(); // problem here
```

Log error from GSON :

**java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to mypackagename.Client**

Is it problem relate with GSON ?

Comment: is there a getData() method in your ServerResults?

Comment: @Jois : Yes, of course.

Comment: Can you please post your full serverresults code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `gson` parse your `json` data. There is no way that `gson` will know that your `data` field contain `client data` or `product data`,as you haven't specified any particular object. So `gson` will convert that data field into map object.

You can try below approach.

Change your `ServerResult` as below.

```
public class ServerResult {
    private int error;
    private String message;
    private String message_app;
    private Map<String, String> data;
}
```

Now create util method to get `Client` data from `Map`.

```
public static Client getClient(Map<String, String> data){
    Client client = new Client();
    client.setClientId(data.get("client_id"));
    client.setClientSecret(data.get("client_secret"));
    return client;
}
```

Now use it like..

```
@Override    
public void onResponse(String response) {              
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ServerResult serverResult = gson.fromJson(response, ServerResult.class); //convert json String to ServerResult object
    Client client = getClient(serverResult.getData());
}
```

similarly you can also get product data from same `ServerResult` object. without creating different parser class.

Comment: @CauCuKien glad it help you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it cannot work that way.
As you wrote, your `data` field may come with different contents (i.e. as different classes) depending on the request.

All Gson can see is your `object data` field in `ServerResult`. 
How is Gson supposed to know which exact kind of object (e.g. your `Client` class) 'hides' within the data object? Gson will not check all available classes from your code and just "try to cast it".

Comment: So can you suggest a right way ? Should I create many models class for each response ?

Comment: You can model your data field as JSONObject (But I haven't tested that)
Edit: dev.bmax suggested that, too :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to declare the 'data' field to be of type com.google.gson.JsonObject and parse it manually by checking what content there is.

For example:

```
JsonObject data = serverResult.getData();
if (data.has("client_id")) {
    //parse it as Client
} else {
    //parse it as another type
}
```